# How to make the ProgressBar in ListView using adapter class?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview

I had tried to use `ProgressBar` in `ListView`, I had used adapter class to display text and `ProgressBar` in `ListView`, but I couldn't get it.

```
public class ProgressBarActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edtTxt;
    Button btn;
    ListView lstExample;
    String txt;
    progressAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> adap;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        edtTxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        adap=new ArrayList<String>();
        lstExample=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
             btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
             {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    txt=edtTxt.getText().toString();
                    if(txt.equals(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        adap.add(txt);
                        String[] arr=adap.toArray(new String[adap.size()]);
                        adapter=new progressAdapter(ProgressBarActivity.this, arr);
                        lstExample.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
            });      

    }
```

This is my adapter class:

```
public class progressAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public  Activity activity;
    String[] str;
    String comment;
    LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    int progressBarStatus=0;
    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();
    TextView t1;

    public progressAdapter(ProgressBarActivity sam,String[] txt) 
    {
        activity=sam;
        str=txt;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return str.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int postion) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return postion;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View  vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress,null);
            t1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            final ProgressBar pro=(ProgressBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

            comment=str[position];
            pro.setVisibility(vi.VISIBLE);

            t1.setText(comment);

        return vi;
    }
}
```

It's running but it's running in all the `ListView`.

Comment: Would you please clarify your question?

Comment: @Hydrangea:Actually I want that progress bar to progress only on the current listview i.e., the current view in which the text is going to post not on all the view,but in this it's displaying for all the view.

Comment: Actually I want that progress bar to progress only on the current listview i.e., the current view where the text is going to post and it should dismiss the progress with in 2 secs,but it is displaying in all the view and not getting disappeared.